# Why does bash printf %q produces different kinds of output?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a shell script and I need to pass in the outputs of one command as an argument to another, so it needs to be escaped properly.  This seems like a textbook use case for `bash`s `printf` builtin with the `%q` format, so here we go:

In file `test1`, I have the following text:

> "I fear not thy epidemic, man," said Ahab from the bulwarks, to
>   Captain Mayhew, who stood in the boat's stern; "come on board." But
>   now Gabriel started to his feet. "Think, think of the fevers, yellow
>   and bilious! Beware of the horrible plague!" "Gabriel! Gabriel!" cried
>   Captain Mayhew; "thou must either&mdash;" But that instant a headlong
>   wave shot the boat far ahead, and its seethings drowned all speech.
>   "Hast thou seen the White Whale?" demanded Ahab, when the boat drifted
>   back. "Think, think of thy whale-boat, stoven and sunk! Beware of the
>   horrible tail!"

In file `test2`, I have the following text:

> But be all this as it may, certain it is that while the subordinate
>   phantoms soon found their place among the crew, though still as it
>   were somehow distinct from them, yet that hair-turbaned Fedallah
>   remained a muffled mystery to the last.

What I find curious is how these two strings are escaped differently by `printf %q`.

```
bcollins$ test1=`cat test1`; printf %q "$test1"
$'"I fear not thy epidemic, man," said Ahab from the bulwarks, to\nCaptain Mayhew, who stood in the boat\'s stern; "come on board." But\nnow Gabriel started to his feet. "Think, think of the fevers, yellow\nand bilious! Beware of the horrible plague!" "Gabriel! Gabriel!" cried\nCaptain Mayhew; "thou must either&mdash;" But that instant a headlong\nwave shot the boat far ahead, and its seethings drowned all\nspeech. "Hast thou seen the White Whale?" demanded Ahab, when the boat\ndrifted back. "Think, think of thy whale-boat, stoven and sunk! Beware\nof the horrible tail!"'

bcollins$ test2=`cat test2`; printf %q "$test2"
But\ be\ all\ this\ as\ it\ may\,\ certain\ it\ is\ that\ while\ the\ subordinate\ phantoms\ soon\ found\ their\ place\ among\ the\ crew\,\ though\ still\ as\ it\ were\ somehow\ distinct\ from\ them\,\ yet\ that\ hair-turbaned\ Fedallah\ remained\ a\ muffled\ mystery\ to\ the\ last.
```

In one, the output is a bash-escaped string, unexpanded.  In the second, the result is fully expanded and escaped.  Why?  How can I make it be consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm that was tricky.

This is happening due to **presence of a non-ASCII character** in your first file as:

```
either—
```

When `printf` spots a `non-ASCII character` it just doesn't escape string inside and uses

```
$'<string>'
```

notation for printing.

Comment: Ah, the emdash!  Good catch.

Comment: Actually, I double-checked my `test1` file, and it's encoded as ascii and the apparent emdash was actually an html entity that wound up copied from fillerati.  I lost track of it between my browser and terminal.

Comment: I think you're right.  It's not the mdash, I'm quite sure, but there must be another non-ASCII character somewhere because I tried it with some different text with obvious UTF-8 characters and after doing `iconv -f UTF-8 -t US-ASCII --unicode-subst="\u%0X"`, I was able to get consistency.

Comment: From the printf output, it looks like the first contains hard linefeeds, and that's probably what's triggering the `$'...'` mode.